# How to use highlight index parameter on ssrs

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, highlighting

I have a report on SSRS and I have just one parameter called SSCC
I want to highlighting for index SSCC
I mean if I used this SSCC number : 350110073200168575
I want to fill color must change yellow, just this number of SSCC

And sometimes my SSCC number will be multiple but I just want to see for one SSCC 
I added screenshot.

You can see my report preview:

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: [Adding Conditional Formatting (Reporting Services)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156400(v=sql.100).aspx) on MS Docs.

> **Changing Text Color Based on an Expression**
>
> To make the contents of a text box render negative values in red for a field called Profit, open the Properties pane and use the following expression in the Color property:

```
=IIF(Fields!Profit.Value < 0, "Red", "Black")
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a condition to the background color of the textbox that will contain the record.  Then compare the field to the parameter value, with your selected colors as the return value.

```
=IIF(Fields!SSCC.Value = @Parameters!SSCC.Value,"Yellow","[Your default color]")
```

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for your answer, I did:) my index value returns on the report more than one. I want to fill color just first value.

Comment: I did like this:
=IIF(Fields!SSCC.Value =Parameters!SSCC.Value ,"Red", "WhiteSmoke")
but I just want to paint first value. How can I do like this? Thanks.

Comment: In your dataset, you may be able to use the windowing functions to get a running count of that value, surfacing that as an additional field to your report.  Then you'd set the color based on that new field.  Outside of that, I can't think of any other way to do it because these expressions are evaluated for every row, based on the data returned.  Within the report, there are very few options for examining the values of other rows.